# Prove that the series of functions converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-(n+1)x}$, does this series converge uniformly in the domain $[r, \infty)$ with $r$ a fixed real number?

Note that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-(n+1)x}=e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-e^{-x})^n$$

So, this looks like a infinite geometric series, for $|-e^{-x}|<1$ (this is $x>0$) we have that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-(n+1)x}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}$$

So the series converges for $x>0$

But what about uniform convergence? note that the convergence is not uniformly in $D=(0, \infty)$ but it does converge uniformly in $[r, \infty)$ with $r>0$ fixed

But how can I guarantee this by definition, i.e., by proving that exists $n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. if $\forall n \geq n_{0}$ and all $\epsilon>0$

$$\sup_{x\in[r, \infty)}|S_{n}(x)-f(x)|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k e^{-(k+1)x} -\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} \right|<\epsilon$$

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k e^{-(k+1)x} -\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}|=|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} (-1)^k e^{-(k+1)x}|\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}  e^{-(k+1)r}$. Can you finish?

Comment: Thanks for this, but just one thing; i dont see why the last expression has a $r$ in place of a $x$,

Comment: $x \geq r$ implies $-(k+1)x\leq -(k+1)r$. @Wrloord

Comment: Ohhh, I have thought about the conclusion maybe assuming that the sequence of partial sums of the last series is uniformly Cauchy and from there I get the $\epsilon$, it is not very clear yet, any suggestions?

Comment: @Wrloord If $a_n \geq 0$ and $\sum a_n <\infty$ then there exists $N$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_n <\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$